# Calculat Specific Gravity (SG) using pressure differential

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, temperature, flow, bernoulli-equation

Can anyone help me to calculate SG in an open tank of fermenting juice? I have two pressure sensors mounted a metre apart. The juice height above the top sensor can vary. The pressure sensors are gauge type.

In an open tank of water I am reading 10.8003 kpa on the top sensor and 20.6776 on the lower sensor so a differential pressure of 9.8777 kpa.

How can I convert this to an SG value? The pressure sensors are corrected for temperature but I am guessing SG will need to be corrected as well which at the time of writing was 20 Celsius.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by SG? If I take the density of your fermenting juice approximately the water density, using DeltaP = \rho g h then I can tell that your sensors are about one meter difference vertically.

Comment: I am wanting to calculate the Specific gravity and then convert this to BRIX

Comment: Why not use a hydrometer? Much more accurate than your plan. You can also measure Brix directly with a refractive index  device.

Comment: Not in 100 tanks at a time. It has to be calculated and the values are used to control the temperature of the ferment.

Answer (score 0):

SG = \Delta P / (g h) where g is the gravitational acceleration, h is the height difference between the two manometers and Delta P is the pressure difference. You must use the hydrostatic pressure formula.

Comment: Thank you so much! Its so simple when you know how. Cheers